# Why does Observable.Do throws InvalidOperationException "Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, observable, xunit, reactivex

I do get an (IMHO) unexpected  Exception `InvalidOperationException` "Sequence contains no elements" in the below code, where I believe this should not be the case. Please see the code, background info and description below.

**The Issue**

For the sake to reproduce it easily and to demonstrate it, the code in the Unit Test using my SUT `Effect` is commented out, and replaced with the given code which should make it clear what I am trying to do and what I am trying to test.

So, I can reduce the question to "Why do I get a "Sequence contains no elements" exception when executing `Observable.Do`, when it is a total valid use case":

```
IObservable<int> observable = Observable.Empty<int>();
```

And, I want to test this, an empty sequence which completes.

**Unit Test**

```
public class EffectTests {

    [Fact]
    public async void TestEmpty() {
        // IObservable<int> observable = Effect<Unit, int>.Empty.Invoke()
        //     .Delay(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2));

        IObservable<int> observable = Observable.Empty<int>()
            .Delay(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2));

        // Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
        // Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Reactive.dll: 'Sequence contains no elements.'
        //    at System.Reactive.Subjects.AsyncSubject`1.GetResult()
        //    at EffectTests.<TestEmpty>d__0.MoveNext() in 
        await observable.Do(
            onNext: _ => AssertEx.Fail()
        );
    }
}

public static class AssertEx {
    public static void Fail(string message = "")
        => throw new Xunit.Sdk.XunitException(message);
}
```

**Background**

I hope, the code in comments and the xUnit test setup shows what I am trying to do:

I have a custom struct `Effect` which basically stores a function returning an `IObservable<T>`. This should show already the fact that an Effect can actual return any kind of observable (via function `Invoke()`). That observable may now return values that will be emitted synchronously or asynchronously, it might fail immediately or succeed, or it might emit one or more values, or none at all.

In my Unit Test, in the case of an `Effect.Empty` the Observable is actually an empty sequence and thus it's intended to not emit any values. So, I precicely added an `Assert.Fail()` when the callback `onNext` would be called.

**Additional Info**

So, the documentation to `Observable.Do` says:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Invokes an action for each element in the observable sequence, and propagates
    //     all observer messages through the result sequence. This method can be used for
    //     debugging, logging, etc. of query behavior by intercepting the message stream
    //     to run arbitrary actions for messages on the pipeline.
```

which clearly does not state anything that it would throw an exception if the sequence is empty. It also cleary states the use case, which is for "debugging, logging, etc.", so I thought that would be a perfect fit for my use case, i.e. Unit Tests.

**My Questions**

1. Why does `Observable.Do` throw the exception?
2. How can I alleviate the issue in my Unit Tests?

There are a lot of questions about "Sequence contains no elements" on SO already, but as far as I could look it up, there is none specifically mention it in regards to `Observable.Do`. But any existing answer is appreciated, too.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution:**

You can use `.DefaultIfEmpty()` to avoid awaiting an empty observer.
In your case:

```
[Fact]
public async void TestEmpty() {
    // IObservable<int> observable = Effect<Unit, int>.Empty.Invoke()
    //     .Delay(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2));

    IObservable<int> observable = Observable.Empty<int>()
        .Delay(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2));

    // Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
    // Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Reactive.dll: 'Sequence contains no elements.'
    //    at System.Reactive.Subjects.AsyncSubject`1.GetResult()
    //    at EffectTests.<TestEmpty>d__0.MoveNext() in 
    await observable.Do(
        onNext: _ => AssertEx.Fail()
    ).DefaultIfEmpty();
}
```

**More information:**

The issue is not with `Observable.Do`, but rather it's the test that eventually await an empty observer.

Like you, I didn't find any documentation of why it behaves like this.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It helped me understand the issue. Seems like, a sequence must contain an element, otherwise certain operators will throw an exception. This behaviour is indeed debated on several places, and many disagree with throwing an exception _in this_ case. IMHO, this is a flaw in the design. Calling operator `DefaultIfEmpty() ` will work, but it's a workaround.  Nonetheless, thanks for this. :)